# How to draw a pushbutton to a tableview cell?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, pyside6

I'm new to PySide6.
I have a table and display it with a `QTableView`. And my data was put into a `QAbstractTableModel`. like this

```py
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    ...

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.model = MyTableModel()
        self.table_view.setModel(self.model)
```

Now, I want to add a `delete` button for each row to delete the related data.

After some searching, I know I should use `QStyledItemDelegate` but I was stuck at the `paint` method and have no idea of how to handle the click signal.

```py
class RefreshButtonDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter: PySide6.QtGui.QPainter, option: PySide6.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem,
              index: Union[PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex, PySide6.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex]) -> None:
        # if last column
        if index.column() == index.model().columnCount() - 1:
            print(index.column())
            print('draw')
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text='delete')
            print(index.model().data(index))
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
```

What should I do then?

Comment: As the function name clearly indicates, `paint()` is just responsible of *painting*. It certainly can *not* handle mouse events. Why don't you just use `setIndexWidget()`?

Comment: Because I'm using ModelView mode, I do not know how to use model data to present a button..

Comment: Sorry but your comment doesn't make any sense. Did you even research what [I was referring to](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget)?